# Checkbox não fica marcado

Tags: php, html, ajax

Tenho um aplicação onde uma tabela é carregada dinamicamente via ajax, e dentro da tabela existe uma condição, caso a condição seja verdadeira eu tenho que carregar uns checkbox ao lado de cada nome que é carregado, só que quando eu carrego minha aplicação e tento escolher um dos checkbox, o ***checkbox*** não permanece checado

***CHAMADA AJAX***

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url:"inserir_sc_ajax.php",
    data:dados,
    success: function(result){
        if(result.length > 2){
            $("#fluxo").html('');
            $("#fluxo").append(result);
        }else{
            var option = "<option value='' >Nao Existe Fluxo para Este Grupo</option>";
            $("#fluxo").html('');
            $("#fluxo").append(option);
        }
    }
});
```

***CÓDIGO***

```
while ($ln2 = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    if($ln2['codNIvel'] == 2){
        echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td> <input type='checkbox' checked name='codRequestManager' value='{$ln2['codUser']}' /> ". $ln2['nome'] ." </td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }else{  
        echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td> ". $ln2['nome'] ." </td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
}
```

Comment: Já tentou checked='checked' ou checked=true ?

Comment: já sim... no código na verdade não é pra ter o "checked", coloquei como teste e esqueci de tirar

Comment: Pode explicar melhor o que pretende. Pretende ter as checkbox selecionadas por defeito?

Comment: quando aparecer minha tabela, se as linhas cairem na condição, vai aparecer os checkbox (desmarcados), aí eu vou clicar em um deles para depois fazer uma outra ação...só que os checkbox não ficam marcados quando eu clico sobre algum deles

Comment: Só vendo o código todo, inclusive o css. Pode ser que esteja algum outro elemento, por exemplo, por cima das checkbox, ou tenha algum disabled = true perdido no código.

Answer (score 1):

Consegui... a tabela da qual eu falava era carregada de acordo com um ***< select >< /select >*** só que eu chamava o ***change*** da seguinte forma fora do ***ready***

```
$(document).change("#fluxo", function(){...}
```

Tudo o que eu fiz foi colocar dentro do ***ready*** e funcionou, ficou da seguinte forma:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#fluxo").change(function(){...}
});
```

Agora o motivo pelo qual não funciona do primeiro jeito eu não sei, mas valew a todos pela ajuda !

Answer (score 0):

Tentou especificar o tipo de dados no ajax? Tipo `dataType: 'html'`

No código PHP eu colocaria tudo em uma variável e retornaria em formato JSON.

Assim:

```
   $retorno['html'] = array(); 
   while ($ln2 = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    if($ln2['codNIvel'] == 2){
        $retorno['html'] .= "<tr>";
            $retorno['html'] .= "<td> <input type='checkbox' checked name='codRequestManager' value='{$ln2['codUser']}' /> ". $ln2['nome'] ." </td>";
        $retorno['html'] .= "</tr>";
    }else{  
        $retorno['html'] .= "<tr>";
            $retorno['html'] .= "<td> ". $ln2['nome'] ." </td>";
        $retorno['html'] .= "</tr>";
    }
}
echo json_encode($retorno);
```

Aí no script ajax ficaria assim:

```
$("#fluxo").append(result.html);
```

Comment: vou tentar, assim que terminar dou minha resposta se funcionou ou não !